# Como usar o mysqli_fetch_all no PHP corretamente?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tenho uma função em PHP utilizando MySQL, segue:

```
public function listAll(){
      $sql = mysqli_query($this->conectar, "SELECT * FROM items");
      $this->desconectar;
      return $sql->fetch_all();
    }
```

minha pagina para instancia:

```
$p = new Items();
$result = $p->listAll();
$r = new ArrayIterator($result);

print_r($r);
```

quando eu dou um `print_r` nela me retorna isso
`ArrayIterator Object ( [storage:ArrayIterator:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => prod test 3)))`

ai quando eu tento chamar o nome me retorna isso:

```
echo $r->current()->nome
```

`Trying to get property of non-object in`

resultado do `print_r($result)`

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => prod test 3)`

Comment: pq precisa de um `ArrayIterator`?

Comment: dá um `print_r($result)` e coloque na pergunta! talvez nem precisa desse ArrayIterator

Comment: Tente utilizar o parâmetro  MYSQLI_ASSOC dentro da função

Comment: o erro está dizendo que o resultado não é um objeto, acredito que porque ele retorna uma array de objetos

Comment: Felipe eu utilizei como o rray disse mas continua o erro `Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) por padrão devolve um array com indices numericos como mostra o `print_r()` na pergunta. Se deseja que esse array retornado se um associativo use a constante `MYSQLI_ASSOC` na chamada da função. Se deseja que o retorna seja um objeto precisa da função [`mysqli_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php) em conjunto com um while.

Mude:

```
return $sql->fetch_all();
```

Para:

```
return $sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

O método `current()` devolve o **array** então pode acessar ele assim:

```
echo $r->current()['nome'];
```

Ou ainda:

```
 $item = $r->current();
 echo $item['nome'] .' - '. $item['outra_chave'];
```

Comment: eu utilizei mas ele continua com o erro quando eu chamo o echo `echo $r->current()->nome` e também quando eu chamo o assim `echo $result->nome`

Comment: quando eu uso o `$r->current()` no `print_r` ele me retorna certinho o valor `Array ( [id] => 3 [nome] => prod test 3)` so que ai eu tento acessar por exemplo o id `$r->current()->id` ele me traz o erro `Trying to get property of non-object`