# Usar mysqli_fetch_all no modo procedural

Tags: php

Estou precisando trazer resultados de um banco de dados que fique dessa forma:

> Fernando Pessoa, Pablo Neruda,Manuel Bandeira

Para isso, estou tentando dessa forma:

```
$sql = mysqli_query(...);
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo join(",",$mostrar["Nome"]);
```

Porém não traz retorno, nem com **var_dump()**. Vi que aqui tem [esse post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/255314/como-usar-o-mysqli-fetch-all-no-php-corretamente), mas não consegui entender muito bem como funciona. Como posso usar no modo procedural?

Quando uso dessa forma:

```
while($cs = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
  echo $cs["Nome"];
}
```

Funciona normalmente!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No modo procedural, o primeiro parâmetro deve ser o resultado de `mysqli_query`

Errado: `mysqli_fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Correto: `mysqli_fetch_all($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`

Como você disse que funciona localmente mas não no servidor, então provavelmente falta instalar a [extenção MySQL Native Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd.install.php) no seu servidor, você pode usar essa função que recebe um [statement](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

```
function fetch($statement)
{
    $metadata = $statement->result_metadata();

    $columnName = array();

    foreach ($metadata->fetch_fields() as $field) {
        $columnName[] = json_decode(json_encode($field), true)['name'];
    }

    $metadata->free_result();

    $columnValue = $columnName;

    if (!$statement->bind_result(...$columnValue)) {
        return null;
    }

    $data = array();

    while($statement->fetch()) {
        $row = array();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($columnName); $i++) { 
            $row[$columnName[$i]] = $columnValue[$i];
        }

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Tente dessa forma, mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Mostra algum erro? A query SQL está correta? Se não estiver o valor de `$sql` pode ser um booleano e não funcionar

Comment: Nenhum erro e a query está certa. Alterei meu post e inclui com o while() que retorna normalmente os resultados.

Comment: Guilherme, sua solução funciona no meu local, porém não no servidor remoto. Acredito que seja alguma configuração de lá. Coloquei uma solução alternativa e agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Infelizmente acredito que o problema seja alguma configuração do servidor, já que a solução do Guilherme funciona no meu local. Para resolver isso, criei uma solução alternativa na própria query caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema que eu, ficando dessa forma:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT *,GROUP_CONCAT( Nomes ORDER BY Nomes ASC SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS NomesUsuarios FROM tabela;");
$cs = mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
echo $cs->NomesUsuarios;
```